# Make "Star" by HTML

Tags: html, css

I need some help with html)

I have this:

[image: picture]

When i press to another "button" (like pig) text in the centre must change to another.

So question: what i need to use to make it. Maybe you have some example.

Comment: As I understand, what you want is once the user clicks the star, the text changes to something else. You can do this with javascript (just some keywords: look for onClick, getElementById, innerHTML), or with jQuery you can even make it fancy, with animations, etc.

Comment: Please include your current code in the question, otherwise you have little chance to get help.

Comment: What exactly you want to know? How to draw a star with html/css, or how to change text on click?

Comment: deeenes thx) It'is helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you can solve your question with this:

```
<html>
</body>
    <script>
    function changeText()
    {
     document.getElementById('MiddleText').innerHTML = 'New Text in the middle';
    }
    </script>
    <p id='MiddleText'>Your text in the middle</p> 
    <input type='myButton' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
</body>
</html>
```